How to check for json response to an api call made from gitlab pipeline?
I want to check the response for the call made in stage create_merger_request and based on the response I have to make another api call such as merge a merge request.
stages:
  - create_branch
  - create_merge_request
  - merge_merge_request

create_branch:
  stage: create_branch
  script:
    - git checkout -b new-feature-branch
    - git push origin new-feature-branch
  only:
    - master

create_merge_request:
  stage: create_merge_request
  script:
    - |
      curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
      --data "source_branch=new-feature-branch&target_branch=master&title=New Feature" \
      "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests"
  only:
    - master
  needs:
    - create_branch

merge_merge_request:
  stage: merge_merge_request
  script:
    - |
      MR_ID=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests?source_branch=new-feature-branch" | jq '.[0].id')
      curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
      --data "merge_when_pipeline_succeeds=true" \
      "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/$MR_ID/merge"
  only:
    - master
  needs:
    - create_merge_request

I am trying to do this using some external tools, but got suggestion from my colleague that we should be able to achieve this within the gitlab pipeline.

Your colleague suggestion is correct. You don't need external tools beyond what's available in the CI environment. check below script, it should solve your problem.
stages:
  - create_branch
  - create_merge_request
  - merge_merge_request

create_branch:
  stage: create_branch
  script:
    - git checkout -b new-feature-branch
    - git push origin new-feature-branch
  only:
    - master

create_merge_request:
  stage: create_merge_request
  script:
    - |
      # Create a merge request
      RESPONSE=$(curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
        --data "source_branch=new-feature-branch&target_branch=master&title=New Feature" \
        "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests")
        
      # Extract the MR ID from the response
      MR_ID=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r '.id')
      
      # Print the MR ID for debugging
      echo "Merge Request ID: $MR_ID"

      # Save MR_ID to a file for use in the next stage
      echo "$MR_ID" > mr_id.txt
  only:
    - master
  needs:
    - create_branch

merge_merge_request:
  stage: merge_merge_request
  script:
    - |
      # Read the MR ID from the file
      MR_ID=$(cat mr_id.txt)
      
      # Merge the merge request
      curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
        --data "merge_when_pipeline_succeeds=true" \
        "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/$MR_ID/merge"
  only:
    - master
  needs:
    - create_merge_request

